# C# цифры после запятой

Tags: c#

Такой вопрос. Допустим у нас есть значение 25.657446842, как я его могу сократить до двух символов после запятой?

Comment: Оно у вас в виде числа с плавающей точкой или в виде строки?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Math.Round(25.657446842, 2) // Выведет 25,66
```

Comment: Вас, возможно, удивит, но: https://ideone.com/vlQX8d

Comment: Так все же нормально.
Если руками заменить `Math.Round(25.657446842, 2)` на 25.66 выходит то же самое

Comment: Мой пойнт в том, что для floating-point понятие «количество десятичных знаков после запятой» вообще не имеет смысла. Число `25.66` не представимо точно в типе данных `double`.

Comment: Это да. Без сомнения. Вообще, малые числа это очень неприятная тема, по крайней мере для меня.

Answer (score 4):

Ещё можно так -

```c#
string result = variable.ToString("#.##");
```

(если просто отсечь знаки, без округления)

Comment: Вообще-то форматирование как раз делает округление.

Comment: -1 этот ответ округляет!

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 25.657446842);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F1}", 123.233424224));
```

F1 - "1" кол-во символов после запятой

Answer (score -1):

```
string s = float.Parse(input[0]).ToString("F4");
            Console.WriteLine(s.Remove(s.Length - 2));
```

Для тех кто хочет без округления

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

```
int fahrenheit = 94;
Single celsius = (Single)(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;  
Console.WriteLine($"The temperature is  { Math.Round(celsius, 2)} celsius.");
```

Comment: Single is equal to float