# Как сделать число с нужным кол-вом знаков после точки? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Есть игра *(кликер)*. Я хочу сделать, чтобы при достижении 1 млн монет у игрока писалось колво млн монет с двумя знаками после запятой.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
BalanceText.text = (Convert.ToDouble(Balance) / 1000000) + "млн$";
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# цифры после запятой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739930/c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте `Balance` изначально `decimal`. Избегайте операций с плавающей точкой (float или double) при работе с финансами.

```
public decimal Balance;
```

Используйте форматирование. Кстати если хотите показать символ доллара, то он ставится перед числом, а не после как с рублями `$1000`.

Научитесь использовать [форматирование чисел](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

```
BalanceText.text = "$" + (Balance / 1000000).ToString("F2") + " млн";
```

Или так, с интерполяцией

```
BalanceText.text = $"${(Balance / 1000000):F2} млн";
```